# Mouse randomly stops responding

Tags: mouse

I am not aware of any system change that could cause this, but sometimes my mouse just stops responding. Its light is still on so the fault is probably not in the hardware.

Syslog at the time the mouse dies looks like this

```
Jun 16 00:15:24 martin-mint kernel: [21426.913233] hid-generic 0003:046D:C041.0009: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.1/input0, status -32
Jun 16 00:15:24 martin-mint kernel: [21426.959700] hid-generic 0003:046D:C041.0009: can't reset device, 0000:00:1a.0-1.1/input0, status -32
Jun 16 00:15:24 martin-mint kernel: [21426.989852] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 7
Jun 16 00:15:24 martin-mint laptop-mode: Laptop mode 
Jun 16 00:15:24 martin-mint laptop-mode: enabled, not active
Jun 16 00:15:24 martin-mint laptop-mode: Laptop mode 
Jun 16 00:15:24 martin-mint laptop-mode: enabled, not active
Jun 16 00:15:24 martin-mint kernel: [21427.231822] usb 1-1.1: new full-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
Jun 16 00:15:25 martin-mint kernel: [21427.875585] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c041
Jun 16 00:15:25 martin-mint kernel: [21427.875596] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jun 16 00:15:25 martin-mint kernel: [21427.875602] usb 1-1.1: Product: USB Gaming Mouse
Jun 16 00:15:25 martin-mint kernel: [21427.875607] usb 1-1.1: Manufacturer: Logitech
Jun 16 00:15:25 martin-mint kernel: [21427.881389] input: Logitech USB Gaming Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.1/1-1.1:1.0/input/input24
Jun 16 00:15:25 martin-mint kernel: [21427.881974] hid-generic 0003:046D:C041.000B: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.1/input0
Jun 16 00:15:25 martin-mint kernel: [21428.083359] hid-generic 0003:046D:C041.000C: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Gaming Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.1/input1
Jun 16 00:15:25 martin-mint laptop-mode: Laptop mode 
Jun 16 00:15:25 martin-mint laptop-mode: enabled, not active
Jun 16 00:15:25 martin-mint laptop-mode: Laptop mode 
Jun 16 00:15:25 martin-mint laptop-mode: enabled, not active
```

Can somebody more experienced than me give some insight?

Comment: That's what happens to an optical mouse as it is nearing it's end of life. The light on the mouse stays on, but the mouse occasionally stops responding. This would usually be accompanied by general sluggishness in the way that the mouse responds or minor jerkiness in the mouse's behavior caused by tiny irregularities in the way that the mouse responds.

Comment: Try with reinstalling the drivers: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install xserver-xorg-input-mouse`

Comment: I should note I also tried plugging a different mouse when the first one stopped responding, but the second one didn't either.

Comment: Happens to USB keyboards too, so it's not related to optical mice.

Comment: This bug seems relevant: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1103164